# How to send date as a parameter to the request in Ksoap2 to consume .Net web service

Tags: web-services, date, blackberry, java-me, ksoap2

I am using KSoap2 for consume web service in my application. I need to send date as parameter in the request.

Can anybody know how to send date as a parameter and send the request and please give the sample code for it.

Does Ksoap2 support date format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It has worked best for me to format the date into a string and pass it through the webservice as a string. When receiving a string you just parse the string for a date. Keep in mind that you will have to know what format the date should be formatted as.

For automatic marshalling you can also get date to work, although you might have to implement a marshaller that support the format you need for your webservice. See the Float example in the ksoap2-android code base.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the KSOAP2-android library. It already has a MarshalDate class that you just need to register to your SoapSerializationEnvelope.

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapRequest);
soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;


new MarshalDate().register(soapEnvelope); //This will enable you to pass a Date object as a parameter to your web service
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell KSOAP how to serialize and deserialize the date - for that you need to write a class that implements the Marshal interface and register the envelope for that Marshal. This also holds for other data types, such as double.

Here is a tutorial on how to do it:

[Implementing KSOAP Marshal Interface](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html)